# BBCode ending tag kills PHP mysqli query

Tags: php, bbcode

I honestly have no idea what's going on.

It works fine, until I put the ending tag on a BBCode tag.

So this would work fine:

```
$article = <<<EOF
<article>
  <code>
  [b]$title
  </code>
</article>
EOF;
```

While this, would kill the whole code and not print any results:

```
$article = <<<EOF
<article>
  <code>
  [b]$title[/b]
  </code>
</article>
EOF;
```

I double checked by putting the exact same code into plain old HTML, and it would display the code just fine. I also tried [/b]$title and that worked, I just can't have an opening AND an ending tag.

Here's the rest of the coding:

```
require ("db_connect.php");

$residential = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM residential ORDER BY id");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($residential)) {
  include "results.php";
  $title = "$row['title']";
  echo $article;
  }
```

Comment: Define "kills". What error do you are? Are you looking at the error message reported by the database? Provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what the PHP for communicating with the database looks like.

Comment: I'll add the rest of the coding. As for kill, I mean, it returns blank results. Code dies, I forgot how to echo an error code so there is none.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` will show the error. Put that at the top of the page.

Comment: Maybe you should have looked up [how to get an error message](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysqli+error&oq=mysqli+error&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2005j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) before reaching out to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: When you haven't done any coding for over a year, you forget the existence of error messages. I'm only just getting off my rust...

Comment: That `$article`snippet is in the included file? Also, you don't need `$title = "{$row[title]}";`, just `$title = $row['title'];` will suffice. Small change, but it removes two characters.

Comment: @Rasclatt oh thanks for that info. I think it's a leftover from copy pasting code. Can't remember why I went with that before.

Comment: Well, you can do it, but it would be better served in something like `echo "Hello, my name is {$row[title]}";` but just by itself can be `$row['title']`

Comment: That `$article` string in the `results.php` correct?

Comment: @Rasclatt ahhh! Yea, that's prolly it. I remember doing that before. But yea, it's a leftover from recycling old coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different string type and order for your loop, see if it works or not:

**results.php**

```
$article = "
<article>
  <code>
  [b]{$title}[/b]
  </code>
</article>";
```

or

```
$article = "
<article>
  <code>
  [b]".$title."[/b]
  </code>
</article>";
```

or

```
ob_start();
?>
<article>
  <code>
  [b]<?php echo $title ?>[/b]
  </code>
</article>
<?php
$article = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Then in the loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($residential)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    include('results.php');
    echo $article;
}
```

or don't include that page in the loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($residential)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo "
    <article>
        <code>
            [b]".$title."[/b]
        </code>
    </article>";
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you! Went with the first one as the coding would get too long to handle with other methods. Still have no idea why it was being picky though...

Comment: Yeah, I generally don't use HEREDOC, I am more comfortable using the other string methods so I couldn't really troubleshoot a HEREDOC syntax error very well without looking through the manual.